# jsx print text conditional for property without value in styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have this component:

```
<Button type="submit" { invalid  ?  'primary': null }>
```

this component is styled component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Button = styled.button`
  font-size:  15px;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: solid 1px  ${(props) => {
      let color;
      if (props.primary) {
        color = 'red';
      } else {
        color = '#ffffff';
      }
      return color;
  }};
  `;
```

I get this error:

> Syntax error: Unexpected token ^invalid, expected ... (64:54)

I need just to send a property 'primary' if invalid is true, to get this:

```
<Button type="submit" primary/>
```

I don't want write:

```
primary = { invalid }
```

the component calls this button is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from './layouts/cssstyled';
const getConditionalProps = ( props) => {
  // fill your `invalid` variable in this function or pass it to it
  const myprops = {};
  myprops.primary = true ;
  myprops.secondary = false;
  return myprops;
}

const Form = (props) => {
  console.log('form props');
  console.log(props);

  const { handleSubmit, invalid, pristine, reset, submitting, t } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <p>Invalid? {JSON.stringify(invalid)}</p>

        <Button type="submit" disabled={submitting}  primary={invalid ? "" : null} >
          Buton styled component does not work
        </Button>
        <button primary={invalid ? "" : null}>  button native works</button>

        <div className="formError">
          {pristine}
          {invalid && t('form.haserrors')}
        </div>

      </div>

    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'CustomerForm', // a unique identifier for this form
})(Form);
```

Comment: The proper way would definitely be for you to write `primary={invalid}`. Is there any reason why not to write that?

Comment: I work with a css library that need just 'primary' , but why is the technical reason i can't print text in jsx?

Comment: @DDave Because react is not a printing library, it's a virtual DOM that is rendered into HTML.

Comment: @Sulthan i've updated my question, look at the example on the react docs, you can print text inside <tags> but not alone...

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean values, so your conditional will become like this:

```
 <Button type="submit" primary={ !!invalid } >
```

Or if you don't want your button to have a primary value when false, you can do this:

```
const button = invalid ? <Button type="submit" primary > : <Button type="submit" >
```

Comment: but I need <Button type="submit" primary/>  not <Button type="submit primary"> , are you sure?

Comment: I mean, i don't want to show 'primary' if invalid is false, in your example primary is printed,  or there is no possible?

Comment: So you can just do something like this :  const button = invalid && <Button type="submit" primary >

Comment: `const button = invalid && <Button type="submit" primary >` in this case if it is invalid the button wont be rendered at all. I don't think that's what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [React-JS Spread Attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes). It is great tool to spread props on a component with conditional behavior:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    // ...

    getConditionalProps() {
        const props = {};
        // fill your `invalid` variable in this function or pass it to it
        if (invalid) {
            props.primary = true;
        }
        return props
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button type="submit"
                    { ...this.getConditionalProps() } />
        );
    }
}
```

Another solution is conditional rendering:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    // ...

    render() {
        return (invalid ?
            <Button type="submit" primary />
            :
            <Button type="submit" />
        );
    }
}
```

Please note that there may be a better solution to your problem: you need to handle the behavior of the `Button` component from inside the component itself instead of trying to decide from the parent component whether to send a specific prop or not. But the solution above does exactly what you are requiring.

Comment: thanks, i can get this <Button type="submit" primary/> ?

Comment: I have updated the answer to put `true` inside of the `primary` prop, which would be equivalent to writing: `<Button type="submit" primary />` or `<Button type="submit" primary={ true } />`. The point is, with the `getConditionalProps` method, you can fill a props object with any values you want based on conditions then spread them in the component using the `...` notation.

Comment: thanks , but your solution does not work with boolen values, does not print the properties, just when the props have string values

Comment: The solution is independant from the value type, can you show me the code  you used and did not work ?

Comment: Anyway, I updated my solution with a second proposition.

Comment: i've update the answer with almost full code, i use directly   myprops.primary = true ; myprops.secondary = false;  but the values in boolean are not printed, but the solutions is  directly with<button primary={invalid ? "" : null}>

Comment: I think you want to write `<Button />` and not `<button />`. I think that is your problem and not the solution.